Are there opinion polls in the US on the handling of the (armed) conflict with Houthis?
The WSJ (editorial board) writes:

Instead of begging for restraint, the U.S. could capitalize on Israel’s gains by taking out Houthi sites and leaders after their next attack on U.S. ships.

Are there opinion polls in the US, on whether the US is doing enough in the fight against the Houthis?
(IIRC, the WSJ board generally has a Republican leaning. The piece also favors an attack on Iran's nuclear facilities, something that Trump recently advocated, contra Biden. So, I have a feeling that the handling of the fight against the Houthis might also become political football soon, if it hasn't already. Hence the Q.)

It's not a commonly covered issue, but scattered polling exists.
Interestingly, this polling by TIPP Insights suggests that the left was largely on board with such action - at least back in January of this year.



I'm unable to locate any more recent polling and it's possible the mood has shifted, especially those who were inclined to blame Israel's action in Gaza for the rise in attacks on Red Sea shipping.

That poll was in early Jan, before US did any strikes, IIRC. It's interesting though that half of the respondents hadn't even heard of Houthi attacks then.

Yes, the mood has shifted: Slight uptick in Americans wanting U.S. to help diplomatically resolve Israel-Hamas war - Confidence in Israeli Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu to do the right thing regarding world affairs remains low ... More Americans say they have little or no confidence in Netanyahu.
